# onchange not getting triggered

Tags: javascript

I have a calendar which comprise of an input tag and an image on click of image calendar popups comes and sets the value for input tag using javascript.

now i have added onchange event on input tag which doesnt gets triggered since m changing the value using javascript, so what should be done to trigger it i dont want to trigger it explcitly

i tried focusing on input on click of image and focus out on setting the data(into input element) but it didnt worked any workaround?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call the `onchange` handler manually.

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/NQCy7/

```
element.value = 'new value';
element.onchange();
```

Answer (score 0):

just tested what you described, it's the same problem here.

a simple workaround would be to call the onchange-method directly (where you're doing the .focus()/.blur() now)